# C identified STACK OVERFLOW

Tags: c, stack-overflow

I've made the code above and I've used 2 different compilers, one says "Segmentation Fault" and the other one says "handle_exceptions: Exception: STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW".
Here is the code.

```
int main() {
    int k, x, f, i, j, tmp, ct;
    scanf("%d %d", &k, &x);
    int w[k];
    for( f = 0; f<k; f++){
        scanf(" %d", &w[f]);
    }
    while(x--){
        scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);
        tmp = 3;
        for(ct = j; i<=ct<=j; ct--){
            if(tmp > w[ct]){
                tmp = w[ct];
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", tmp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've commented this code, line by line, and testing and I've the error here:

```
int w[k];
```

I don't know what I can do, because the *k* variable is already defined when the declaration of this vector happens. Can somebody help me?

Comment: if (k > 9000000) perror("I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that");

Comment: What is the value of `k`? That is, what is your input? The stack size is limited so a large value of `k` will overflow the stack. Also, should check the return value of `scanf` before using `k`. And finally, probably better to use dynamic memory rather than allocate on the stack when allocating memory based on user input.

Comment: `for(ct = j; i<=ct<=j; ct--){` just doesn't look good.

Comment: Yes, this probably has your `ct` variable going negative. You should learn how to use a debugger or some tool like valgrind.

Comment: @wildplasser but it is for a challenge and decreasing integers is faster than increasing integers.

Answer (score 3):

If you defined an array like this:

```
int w[k];
```

It will be stored in the stack, which has a limited size.

If you initialize with `malloc` the data will be store in the heap (which also has a limited size, but it will allow you to store more data)

```
int *w = malloc(sizeof(int) * k);
```

Have you tried this?

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) for a difference between stack vs heap.

Always checked the returned value from `malloc()`, this is just an example, but it is a bad practice to not the [returned value of malloc()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/).

Comment: Do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends in C! And `malloc` does not initialize anything. That would be `calloc`. Also, these are different semantics: try `sizeof(w)` for both.

Comment: @Olaf what is the issue of casting what malloc is returning? it's part of the documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

Comment: @cacho C is not c++. If you get errors and you need to cast malloc in C, well probably because you are using a c++ compiler.

Comment: @cacho: As Michi stated. C and C++ are different languages. (You do not think C# is the same either, don't you?). Do not use C++ resources to learn C programming! Perhaps a good C book and a good C++ book might give you hints.

Comment: that link is from the C LIBRARY, and they DO cast the malloc return value. You don't think that because the domain name is "cplusplus.com" then all of its content MUST be C++ right? @Olaf

Comment: @cacho: Point is, there will be no warning if you do, because you are expected to know what you do in C. Heck, a cast does actually **instruct** the compiler to shut up. I will not discuss this further, there are enough answers here already about this subject. Just as you post refer to **some** C library, that is not authoritative. The only such source for C does [**not** cast](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p23) (just search the text for `malloc`, there are many other examples)!

Comment: Kernighan and Ritchie, who wrote C are casting from malloc  (http://www.iups.org/media/meeting_minutes/C.pdf) @Olaf

Comment: @cacho: You might have noticed C has evolved quite much since K&R C. In K&R you did not have prototypes and _more important_ `malloc` actually returned `char *`, not `void *`, so you **did** have to cast! Please read the normative reference, not some ancient books or C++ references.

Comment: @Olaf The opinion of stackoverflow users is not authoritative either, no matter how high their 'reputation' is. Casting it is legal C code. That's a fact. Everything else is opinion, which by definition cannot be proven wrong or right.

Comment: @LarsFriedrich: Where did I mention reputation here? Did you even read the standard or at least the paragraphs I linked? However, If any of my students does add an unnecessary cast, he will get a malus. You seem to hate your compiler as you keep it from helping typechecking your source. No wonder C has such a bad reputation for some (sad enogh: many of them use it exactly as you propose: as some kind of assembler). There is, however, no use in trying to talk someone out of ignorance, so I leave here.

Comment: @Olaf Feel free to assign grades to your students by checking the size of the source code file. The statement that a non-existent cast helps the compiler in type-checking is ridiculous. There is a difference in `x = 4 * sizeof(int) + 8 * sizeof(int);` versus `x = 12 * sizeof(int);`. Not for the compiler or the result. But for the human. And it is the human error you need to eliminate, his errors about the code, the intention, the semantics - not optimize code by file size. And that's not called ignorance, but experience.

Comment: @LarsFriedrich: Last posting: Please discuss this with the standard commitee members. They apparently share my position (or I do share their position), but apparently you refuse to read the links I posted. Read what the word "malus" means before talking nonsense. And there ist nothing gained, but much to be lost if you do cast if you forget to `#include <stdlib.h>, at least for pre-C99 (which enforces prototypes).

Comment: @cacho what should I modify in this code? I don't know how to do it. I've studied pointers but I don't understand how can I make it.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot define a variable size during run-time unless you use dynamic memory allocation.

As I can see, you are trying to set the variable size based on the user's input.

To do this, you must use dynamic memory allocation.

```
scanf("%d %d", &k, &x);
if(k > MAX_SIZE) {
    return -1;
}
int *w = malloc(sizeof(int) * k);
```

Now you have a memory allocated based on the size entered by user's input. But make sure that you are imposing some limits, because the heap memory is limited.

Comment: This is not true of `c`, which can have [Variable Length Static Arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)

Comment: Variable Length Arrays (VLA) support is mandatory in C99 and is optionally supported in C11.

Comment: @Ben: A VLA cannot be `static`, but is always `auto`.

Comment: @Olaf yes you are right, i got carried away with all the names of things.